# Bash print out line if third column exists

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script file that includes first name, last name and phone number that are seperated by space. Not everyone have phone number and i want to print out the names that do have a phone number.
The file looks something like this

```
Andy Frey 592895
Gregory Simons 6356345
George Hillton 
Fredrik Thomson 125423
```

Comment: I'd probably (as a first cut) just `grep` the file for `[0-9]`.

Comment: What did you tried? SO is not a code service.

Comment: I have tried grep, and split them into arrays. But didn't get it to work. :S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it easily with `awk`:

```
[cnicutar@piper ~]$ awk 'NF==3' names 
Andy Frey 592895
Gregory Simons 6356345
Fredrik Thomson 125423
```

With straight bash:

```
while read -a arr
    do if [ -n "${arr[2]}" ]
    then
        echo ${arr[@]};
    fi
done < names
```

Comment: Good one, +1. Also `awk '$3>0' file` can make it... or even `awk '$3' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, didn't think to just check the field, pretty cool!